# How do i make my bash script on download automatically turn into a terminal command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, command

I am planning on writing a bash script and I going to put it on GitHub. When users download it, I want it to turn into a terminal command. I know how to do this manually but I do not know how to do it in the script so that it would automatically do it.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: I would not blindly run a shell script from an untrusted source. Take me as the average user here

Comment: You cannot do better than giving your users the command they need to download and run the script. You can't change your script so that it will run as soon as it's downloaded. Users get to choose what they do with a downloaded file.

Comment: @jeremysprofile, Ok

Comment: @hek2mgl, I understand what you are saying but you can see all of the source code on the download webpage.

Comment: @TheCoderBoss531 Ok, fair point

Comment: @hek2mgl - that's pretty naive ... https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2016/05/26/why-you-cant-trust-things-you-cut-and-paste-from-web-pages/  https://www.lifehacker.com.au/2016/05/be-careful-when-you-copy-and-paste-code-from-the-internet/

Comment: @tink Yeah, that's scary, but I think this question was about a shell script which executes automatically after download in terminal. No javascript involved :)

Comment: @hek2mgl, Yeah.